# How to display firebase realtime database array into list in Ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic5

I want to display `enquiryContacted` array into Ionic list. 
Ts code is as follows

```
 let userDoc = this.firestore.doc<any>('users/' + userId);
  userDoc.valueChanges()
  .subscribe((user)=> {
    user=user;
    const contactedEn = user.enquiryContacted;
    console.log('get contacted enq in :',contactedEn)
   return contactedEn;
  })
```

Html code is here

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item>Favourite Segment</ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let counter of contactedEn; let i = index">
         {{contactedEn[i]} }
      </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

I am not able to see any results on HTML.

See this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you must check this :
    In Firebase database we use this.firebase.database not 
    Firestore, so your code should be like :

```
this.firebase.databse.
ref(‘users/${userid}/enquiryContacted’)
.once(‘value’, (snapshot) => {
snapshot.forEach(snap => {
this.contactdEn.push(snap.val());
});
});
```

I hope this will fix your problem.